# How do I create an element in the Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I would like to add a new element to the page in Chrome Dev tools. This seems like fairly obvious functionality but I can't seem to find it.

Does Chrome allow me to create elements in the DOM tab? I realize I could make something from the JS console, but would rather something on the DOM tab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just right click on the parent element, change to 'Edit as HTML' and then add whatever elements you want...

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs the F2 key should toggle the selected element in and out of edit mode so you can add an element within.

Unfortunately, I am using a Chromebook that has no F2 key.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just fire up the console and append an element. For example, if I were to do the below on this particular stackoverflow.com post:

```
$('.postcell').append('<code>Testing Element Insertion via Chrome</code>');
```

I'd then see the newly appended element immediately visible in the Elements tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Control-click in the `Elements` panel and selecting `Edit as HTML` is probably the best way to go, but you could also in the console (for curiosity's sake, and with no need for jQuery):

```
var child = document.createElement('div');
var parent = document.getElementByClassName('parent');
parent.appendChild(child);
```

Cheers!